# Modular Firebase Admin Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there or will there be modular Firebase Admin Database functions i.e. update(), get(), set(), ref() etc.? Maybe there is a workaround?

Else I would have to code equal functions twice, like "craftBuilding()" on server (admin) and one for client.

Tried to:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set, update, child, onChildAdded } from 'firebase-admin/database';
```

Error:

> The requested module 'firebase-admin/database' does not provide an export named 'ref'

I expected to be able to use firebase rtdb functions like on client-side, to not code identical functions twice.

Comment: To my knowledge as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#node.js), the only versions available are namespaced.

Answer (score 1):

Since Firebase Admin is namespaced, `ref` is available after you initialize.

```js
import { ref, update, set } from '@path/yourAdminFunctions';

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Initialize Admin SDK

var db = admin.database();
export db;

const dbReference = ref("your reference here");
const IDSnapFromQuery = query(dbReference, ["ID", "==", 10]);
```

You could modularize it yourself by creating functions for the operations you require in a separate file:

```js
import { db } from '@path/yourMainFile';

export function ref(databaseReference) {
  return db.ref(databaseReference);
};

// for query pass in the db.ref instance you're using
export function query(dbReference, queryParams) {
  // identify what query params are e.g. ID == 10 in this example
  // note that you will have to code the queryParams filter, I have left it out

  dbReference
    .orderByChild('ID')
    .equalTo(10).on('child_added',
  (snapshot) => {
    return snapshot;
  });
}

// do the same for update, set etc
```

You can read more on the [admin SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#node.js).

Comment: This sounds like a possible workaround, would this also work for these functions: get, set, remove, update, query, child, orderByChild, equalTo, startAt, endAt, limitToFirst, limitToLast, onChildAdded, onChildChanged, onChildRemoved

Comment: It should be able to work although its untested with them. I have doubts about are the event listeners since it would require you to pass info back and forwards between files, but its plausible.

Comment: I am struggling on query, do you have a trick to do there? My whole code uses query(reference, operation(String), limiter(Integer/String)). How would you convert it, so that it translates internally to reference.operation(String).limiter(Integer/String)?

Comment: I've added how I would do `query` - there is a bit of work for you to do here to convert it all. Firebase Admin is a little finicky. I understand the query above is not an exact conversion since it actually performs the query instead of waiting for `.get()`. You could match it exactly by declaring query an object with a `get` method. I hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: This is how I use it:get(query(this.areasRef, orderByChild('type'), equalTo(1))).then(snapshotAreas => { ... }), so get() is already used or do I get something wrong? Also I think my issue is to code the queryParams filter.

Comment: As I explained in the comment above, `get` is already used, I'm not sure that you can create the query then manually trigger it. Potentially you could, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The Admin SDK is not totally modular yet but has some function such a [`getDatabase()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.database#getdatabase) starting `V10`.

```js
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase-admin/database';
// TODO: Initialize Admin SDK

const db = getDatabase();

// usage
const ref = db.ref('../../..')
```

I would recommend using latest version of the SDK along with the existing syntax but use newer modular imports.